# Rank of a matrix with two parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

Find the rank of the matrix $A$:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & 1-a & 1 \\
b & -a & b \\ a-b & b & 1\end{bmatrix}$ with $a , b \in \mathbb{R}$

I know that I could take the determinant to check for rank 3, but how would I do it for cases of rank 2 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: compute a row-echelon form of $A$. The rank is the number of non-zero lines in such a form.

Comment: Is it possible to use column operations here too? I applied $E_{21} (-1)$, $E_{2}  (-1)$, $E_{23} (-1)$ , $E_{31} (\frac{-(a-b)}{a}) $ and that got all the entries necessary for row-echelon except for $a_{32}$ which is the one I am missing - but it all got very messy... I think column operations could help a bit

Comment: @Enrique Yes, column operations work just as well